# Statistical guarantee on the effectiveness of a kernel density estimation

Tags: statistics, normed-spaces, density-function, estimation, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I have recently started studying about kernel density estimations. For reference, if one is given if $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is an i. i. d. sample drawn from an (unknown) distribution with an unknown $f$ density function, then the *kernel density estimator* of $f$ is the following:
$$\hat{f}_h(x) := \frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n K \Big(\frac{x-x_i}{h} \Big),$$
where $K$ is the kernel.

I started to look for any literature, which states something about the "effectiveness" of this estimation, such as [1](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2463676.2465319) and [2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2288344).

What I seem unanble to find is a theoretical guarantee for the norm of the difference between the original and the estimated density function, namely the term $||\hat{f}_h - f||_p$ for some $p$.

Is there a theorem that states something as follows: for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that
$$\mathbb{P}(||\hat{f}_h - f||_p > \varepsilon) < 1-\delta?$$

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are results bounding $\lVert\hat{f}_h - f\rVert_p$ for any $p$. The results depend on the properties of the kernel $K$, the smoothness $s$ of the density $f$, the number of dimensions $d$, and the decay rate of the bandwidth $h$.

Roughly speaking, for an $s$-Hölder density $f$ on $\mathbb R^d$, if your kernel $K$ satisfies $\int x^\alpha K(x) = 0$ for all multi-indices $\alpha$ with $\lvert \alpha \rvert \in [1, s-1]$, and your bandwidth $h$ decays at the asymptotic rate:
$$
h_n \sim\begin{cases}
n^{-1/(2s+d)}, &\quad p < \infty,\\
(n/\log(n))^{-1/(2s+d)}, &\quad p = \infty,
\end{cases}$$
you can expect the optimal rates of convergence:
$$
\mathbb E [\lVert \hat f_h - f \rVert_p] = \begin{cases} O(n^{-s/(2s+d)}), &\quad p < \infty,\\
O((n/\log(n))^{-s/(2s+d)}), &\quad p = \infty.\end{cases}
$$

You can get an introduction to these results in section 1.2 of Tsybakov's [Introduction to Nonparametric Estimation](https://books.google.com/books?id=mwB8rUBsbqoC); for more details, you might want to check out the references in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-39/issue-3/Bandwidth-selection-in-kernel-density-estimation--Oracle-inequalities-and/10.1214/11-AOS883.full) by Goldenshluger and Lepski.

Edit: it's worth noting that if you want finite-time error bounds, or confidence sets for $f$, these aren't possible without prior knowledge of $f$. As an example, fix a kernel $K$ and bandwidth $h$, and consider the error in estimating the densities $f_k(x) = 1 + \cos(k \pi x)$ on $[0, 1]$, for integers $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Just one question: next to the expected value of the convergence, is it possible to obtain a high-probability result too such as the one I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Yes, you can use Markov's inequality on the above bounds to get bounds in probability. (For $p < \infty$, the same bounds hold for $\mathbb E[ \lVert \hat f_h - f\rVert_p^p]^{1/p}$, which will give better results.)

Comment: (Or for $p=\infty$, the errors can be shown to be [asymptotically Gumbel](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-1/issue-6/On-Some-Global-Measures-of-the-Deviations-of-Density-Function/10.1214/aos/1176342558.full).)